# replace strings with double quotes in a text file

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

I'm using the following command:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/EmployeeDataModel/EmployeeData/g;' *.java
```

This changes stuff like:

```
class EmployeeDataModel to class EmployeeData
```

However, when taking stuff like:

```
class="EmployeeDataModel"
```

It doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there any solution against this?

Comment: It does. Simply put the above two lines in one file and try the script. The problem is buried somewhere elsewhere...

Comment: it must work! There is no reason why it would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually sure ?
Here is my first file :

```
$ cat perl_test
class EmployeeDataModel
class="EmployeeDataModel"
```

Now with your perl replacement :

```
$ cat perl_test | perl -pi -w -e 's/EmployeeDataModel/Test/g'
class Test
class="Test"
```

You must have done something wrong, maybe a typo in your string content, or something like that.

Comment: Well, try it, copy/paste it, and you'll see that it works exactly as expected. Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$echo class="EmployeeDataModel" |sed s/EmployeeDataModel/EmployeeData/g
class="EmployeeData"
```

And [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) also works:

```
$echo class="EmployeeDataModel" |perl -pi -w -e s/EmployeeDataModel/EmployeeData/g;
class="EmployeeData"
```

Comment: Yes -- it does make 'both' changes (really, there's only one, but you're choosing to regard them as different).